# Time series plots Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When plotting each dataset alone I get a time series line, but when combining the 2 data sets in one, the graph turns spotty. How to change the dots to time series for both graphs.

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
name1=pd.read_csv('name1.csv', sep=',')
name2=pd.read_csv('name2.csv', sep=',')
name1.UTC=pd.to_datetime(name1.UTC)
name2.UTC=pd.to_datetime(name2.UTC)
name1.set_index('UTC', inplace=True)
name2.set_index('UTC', inplace=True)
name1=name1[np.isfinite(name1['Soil'])]
name2=Til[np.isfinite(name2['Soil'])]
name1Soil=Ott[['Soil']]
name2Soil=Til[['Soil']]
df_rm=pd.concat([name1Soil.rolling(400).mean(), 
name2Soil.rolling(400).mean()], axis=1)
df_rm.plot(figsize=(40,20), linewidth=10, fontsize=30) 
plt.xlabel('Date-Time', fontsize=30);
plt.ylabel('Soil', fontsize=30);
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of concatenating the two time series, try plotting the two of them separately:

```
df1 = name1Soil.rolling(400).mean()
df2 = name2Soil.rolling(400).mean()
plt.figure(figsize=(1,1))
df1.plot(linewidth=10, fontsize=30, color='green') 
df2.plot(linewidth=10, fontsize=30, color='blue') 
plt.xlabel('Date-Time', fontsize=30);
plt.ylabel('Soil', fontsize=30);
plt.show()
```

Here's an example of how to plot multiple lines on one graph:

```
t = np.arange(0, 2, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t + 2)

plt.plot(t, s1, color='blue')
plt.plot(t, s2, color='green')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to plot them on the same graph (not separately)

Comment: This will plot the in the same graph

Comment: I don't follow! your solution will plot 2 separate graphs. I want df1 and df2 on the same graph

Comment: I want both plots on the same axis